# How do I check if a value exists in Column A of any sheet and return the text in Column B in the row where it is true?

Tags: excel

I am working on a  calculator for remodeling homes, I have about 10 sheets for different rooms. I want all the data compiled in a separate sheet that I will use for importing. I want to search all sheets Column A for a specific cost code such as "9600 Flooring", and if it exists, return the contents from Column B, such as "Install flooring in Bedroom 3".

What would be the cleanest way to do this? I've tried if statements but it gets quite complex and lots of spill errors.

Comment: check https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/02/12/vlookup-multiple-sheets-excel-examples/

Comment: Thanks, VLOOKUP works if the code only appears once. I have for instance 3 codes on one sheet and it is only returning for the first match. How can I make it continue to search for all instances of a code such as "6200 Finish Carpentry"?

Here is my code so far, maybe there is a more elegant/easier way to do it?


="Install flooring in the following rooms: "& CHAR(10) & CHAR(10) & VLOOKUP(A2,Kitchen!A2:H37,8,0)& CHAR(10) & VLOOKUP(A2,Den!A2:H37,8,0)& CHAR(10) & VLOOKUP(A2,Study!A2:I37,8,0)& CHAR(10) & VLOOKUP(A2,'Master Bed'!A2:H36,8,0)& CHAR(10) & VLOOKUP(A2,'Bed 1'!A2:H36,8,0)&...